# Changing sent HTML files using express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to set up a basic login page using express, socket.io, and nodejs. I initially serve the client an index page using:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

I have the logic for authentication set up. I need to know how to then route my user to the successful login page. I am having trouble understanding the way this middleware works, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to check the `req.user` object, it will hold the current logged in user object, that is a good practice to fill this `req.user` if you are building your own auth layer, I'm not sure if you are doing that or not, but I would recommend using the very good [`passport` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport)

So you can have something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if(req.user) { // user is logged in
        res.send(__dirname + '/index.html');
    } 
    else { // anonymous user
        res.send(__dirname + '/login.html');
    }
});
```